# How to print a chart rendered by code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, chart.js

I am using ChartJS library to generate a report at runtime, and on the page we also have a print button, the button prints a div:

```
<div id="printThis">
    <h3 id="titulo_grafica"></h3>
    <canvas id="graficaMedidas" width="200" height="100"></canvas>
</div>
```

I dont think I need to paste the code here to render the picture, but its a nice looking line chart.

the javacript is this:

```
  document.getElementById("btnPrint").onclick = function () {
            printElement(document.getElementById("printThis"));
            printElement(document.getElementById("printThis2"), true, "<hr />");
            window.print();
        }
```

Comment: Are you open to using any plugins?

Comment: What exactly is the problem? It's really not clear.

Comment: yes I am open to use any plugin, the problem is that when I print the page a char with an html table then the chart is blank and I only see the html table.

Answer (score 3):

**[html2canvas](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/)**

> This script allows you to take "screenshots" of webpages or parts of
>   it, directly on the users browser. The screenshot is based on the DOM
>   and as such may not be 100% accurate to the real representation as it
>   does not make an actual screenshot, but builds the screenshot based on
>   the information available on the page.

**[jsPDF](https://parall.ax/products/jspdf)**

> A HTML5 client-side solution for generating PDFs. Perfect for event
>   tickets, reports, certificates, you name it!

**[FileSaver.js](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/)**

> FileSaver.js implements the saveAs() FileSaver interface in browsers
>   that do not natively support it. There is a [FileSaver.js demo](http://eligrey.com/demos/FileSaver.js/) that
>   demonstrates saving various media types.

Put it all together and use [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/) to bind your actions. This will generate a PDF that can either be saved, printed, or viewed.

```
<script src="/path/to/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/path/to/html2canvas.js"></script>
<script src="/path/to/jspdf.min.js"></script>
<script src="/path/to/FileSaver.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $('#btnPrint').on('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        html2canvas($('#printThis'), {
            onrendered: function(canvas) {
                var imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');
                var doc = new jsPDF('landscape');
                doc.addImage(imgData, 'JPEG', 15, 45, 270, 125);
                doc.save('download.pdf');
                return false;
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

**For just print only using html2canvas:**

```
<script src="/path/to/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/path/to/html2canvas.js"></script>
<script>
    $('#btnPrint').on('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        html2canvas($('#printThis'), {
            onrendered: function(canvas) {
                var imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg'); 
                var windowContent = '<!DOCTYPE html>';
                windowContent += '<html>'
                windowContent += '<head><title>Print canvas</title></head>';
                windowContent += '<body>'
                windowContent += '<img src="' + imgData + '">';
                windowContent += '</body>';
                windowContent += '</html>';
                var printWin = window.open('', '', 'width=340,height=260');
                printWin.document.open();
                printWin.document.write(windowContent);
                printWin.document.close();
                printWin.focus();
                printWin.print();
                printWin.close();
                return false;
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

You could do this without the use of jQuery or any plugins, but you'll have to target the canvas directly without any HTML using just the [HTMLCanvasElement.toDataURL()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL) method:

```
<script>
    document.getElementById('btnPrint').onclick = function () {
        var imgData = document.getElementById('graficaMedidas').toDataURL('image/jpeg');
        var windowContent = '<!DOCTYPE html>';
        windowContent += '<html>'
        windowContent += '<head><title>Print canvas</title></head>';
        windowContent += '<body>'
        windowContent += '<img src="' + imgData + '">';
        windowContent += '</body>';
        windowContent += '</html>';
        var printWin = window.open('', '', 'width=340,height=260');
        printWin.document.open();
        printWin.document.write(windowContent);
        printWin.document.close();
        printWin.focus();
        printWin.print();
        printWin.close();
    }
</script>
```